# How to handle windows security pop up (you are about to view pages over a secure connection) of IE11 using ie capabilities in Selenium web-driver?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, desiredcapabilities

I'm connecting to my application over VPN and i get security error pop up something like this:
[IE11 Security pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOeuS.png)

I have handled it using AUTOIT for now, but i wanted to know if there is a way to handle it using ie Desired capabilities???

Comment: Selenium does not have the capability to handle IE "Windows Security" pop up. 
Not even through "switch alert accept/ dismiss" concept. you are using autoit is correct and if you want to change you can use sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is an automation testing tool which supports only web application testing, that means, it doesn’t support windows based applications and window alert/ popup/ dialog are one of them. For a work around, you can refer this link. https://www.joecolantonio.com/selenium-how-to-handle-windows-based-dialogs-and-pop-ups/